# What is the best practice to have partitions on foreign server?

Tags: postgresql

This question is for postgres 12 or 13.

I have one large table with hot and cold data. A field status=0 means it's cold and will never be updated.

The table is partitioned on field status. Hot data goes to "working" table (fillfactor of 40%, SSD) and cold data goes to archive table. The archive table is then partitioned again by date (one per month) for easy removal later.

All archive data will be on anoter server (fillfactor of 100% as there's never any updates, HDD).

So we have.

```
my_table                                                           server : hot
   -> my_table_work (status!=0)                                    server : hot
   -> my_table_archived (status==0)                                server : ???
      -> my_table_archived_2021_01 (2020_12<creation_date<2021_02) server : cold
      -> my_table_archived_yyyy_mm                                 server : cold
      -> ...
```

My question is : where should I put the my_table_archived ? Is it better to

(1) have it on the hot server and declare its sub partitions as foreign tables so the hot server put data directly into remote my_table_archived_yyyy_mm.

or (2) create one foreign table pointing to my_table_archived on remote archive server, then create sub partitions on remote archive server.

What are the pros an cons of each method ?

Edit : I must say that there are intensive jobs done on archived data and we don't want those tasks to interfere with the hot data processes.

Comment: How do you define "better?"  Do you want more speed, or less storage space?  Do you want code elegance? Less network traffic?  What are you optimizing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey all this. I want to know if there are pro or cons of using one method vs the other. I don't see how could one of them being faster or use less trafic or diskspace. If you know please write an answer. I want to know pitfalls I'm not aware of.

Comment: I doubt you can have all of those things at the same time.  You need a goal, and "better" is not specific enough.

Comment: Neither is "pros and cons."  That's a laundry list.  To do justice to such a list would require a highly detailed answer that's probably out of scope here.

Comment: Also, consider posting your question on ServerFault *instead of here.*  They specialize in this sort of thing, and are probably in a better position to give you the kind of detailed answer that you require.

Comment: I would not use foreign tables at all, but attach the slow storage directly to the server and define a tablespace on it. That would be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you @LaurenzAlbe I edited the question : I must say that there are intensive jobs done on archived data and we don't want those tasks to interfere with the hot data processes. That's why there another server.